# Quotient of Lie groups are manifolds?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let be $G$ a lie group and $H$ a closed subgroup of $G$. I don't know how can I prove that the topological space $G/H$ has a structure of smooth manifold on it. Can anyone suggest me an answer or a text where I can read about this statement?

Answer (score 3):

See e.g. Theorem 21.17 (the Homogeneous Space Construction Theorem) in John Lee’s *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*